# Keyboard not working properly in KDE after upgrade to Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: keyboard, kde, 16.10

After having updated Kubuntu from 16.04 (with kubuntu backports ppa enabled) to 16.10 my **keyboard** does record only a few keys (it **ignores most keystrokes**).

This happens only **in plasma** (e.g. Krunner, Application launcher,password dialogues).  However, this does **not** happen in the terminal and **in applications** (e.g. Libreoffice, firefox, guake, telegram, plasma-discover, kate).

The behavior is irrespective of the keyboard layout chosen (DE,GR,US)

Nonetheless it is very annoying as

1. I am used to using Alt-F2 + typing to open my applications
2. I cannot run any GUI applications requiring root (e.g. my own scripts to mount my work network places into my filesystem)

### What I have done

Deleting all files under `~/.config` containing plasma by running `rm *plasma*` did not change anything.

Similarly, deleting all files under `~/.cache` containing plasma by running `rm *plasma*` did not change anything.

When I run

```
killall plasmashell #to stop plasmashell
kstart plasmashell #to restart plasmashell
killall krunner #to stop krunner
krunner #to start krunner
```

and the following to restart polkit-kde-authentification-agent-1

```
killall polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1 &
```

as described in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-settings/+bug/1633721), the aforementioned problems seem to be resolved.

However, they reappear on each restart. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-settings/+bug/1633721) bug replacing ibus for fcitx solved my problem:

```
sudo apt purge ibus
sudo apt install fcitx
sudo dpkg-reconfigure fcitx
sudo reboot
```

Strange thing, after updating to 17.04 I had to redo the above steps...
This is some persistent thing. After updating to 17.10 I had to reinstall ibus to rectify [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966775/error-found-when-loading-etc-profile), and then redo the above steps as this problem recurred. (This however leaves me with the problem described in the linked question).

Comment: This works for me

Comment: I had the same problem on kubuntu 18.10 and this has solved my problem. thanks.

Comment: Purging `ibus` was enough for me. By purging it, I've noticed it was installed by `zoom`, which explains why the issue only appeared after rebooting my computer following the installation of zoom a few days back.

Comment: KDE Neon on Ubuntu 18.04 - didn't work for me. There is also no inbuilt virtual keyboard I can just open, and I can't even get into a terminal session! But the keyboard works without issues outside of Plasma...

Comment: Thank you! Solved issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

KDE on Debian 9 here.

I also looked at the same bug report, but am using a different solution now:  I put a small script into `~/.config/autostart_scripts` and made it executable:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# necessary for starting ibus which was installed as a dependency of Zoom.
ibus-daemon -d --desktop=KDE
```

IBus was required for Zoom for me as well, and this solution seems to work for me so far.