# "Error found when loading /etc/profile"

Tags: ibus, 17.10

**The following problem persists even after upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04:**

After upgrading my Kubuntu 17.04 to  17.10 by running

```
do-release-upgrade
```

I get the following error message after each reboot.

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile:\n\n/usr/share/im-    
config/data/21_ibus.rc line 6: /usr/bin/ibus-daemon: No such     
file or directory\n\nAs a result the session will not be configured correctly.   
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

[image: IMG:]

```
cat -n /usr/share/im-config/data/21_ibus.rc
```

Line 6 reads:

```
IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=0 /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --daemonize --xim --address 'unix:tmpdir=/tmp/ibus'
```

Unfortunately I don't know what this is. Indeed there is no file `/usr/bin/ibus-daemon`

Also:

```
bruni@Inspiron-5547:~$ sudo apt purge ibus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'ibus' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How could I fix the problem as soon as feasible?

why is there a /usr/share/im-config/data/21_ibus.rc used when **ibus is not installed?**

**EDIT**
I guess the culprit in my /etc/profile is the file /etc/profile.d/input-method-config.sh

This reads:

```
# /etc/profile.d/input-method-config.sh              
#                                                    
# This is a temporary measure which works around     
# https://launchpad.net/bugs/1720250                 

if [ -z "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" -o -n "$GTK_IM_MODULE" ]; then                                             
    return                                           
fi                                                   

. /etc/X11/Xsession.d/70im-config_launch             
if [ "$IM_CONFIG_PHASE" = 1 ]; then                  
    export IM_CONFIG_PHASE=2                         
    . /usr/share/im-config/xinputrc.common           
    if [ -r "$IM_CONFIG_XINPUTRC_USR" ]; then        
        . $IM_CONFIG_XINPUTRC_USR                    
    elif [ -r "$IM_CONFIG_XINPUTRC_SYS" ]; then      
        . $IM_CONFIG_XINPUTRC_SYS                    
    fi                                               
    export XMODIFIERS                                
    export GTK_IM_MODULE                             
    export QT_IM_MODULE                              
    export QT4_IM_MODULE                             
    export CLUTTER_IM_MODULE                         
fi
```

also:

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP                                                
KDE
```

and

```
echo $GTK_IM_MODULE
ibus
```

I guess the problem is that **$GTK_IM_MODULE** returns ibus, even though ibus is not installed and not used.

Installing ibus removes the problem described in the question at hand, but leads to the more severe problem described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838613/keyboard-not-working-properly-in-kde-after-upgrade-to-kubuntu-16-10) question, so I removed ibus again.

Comment: 17.10 uses a new desktop and wayland, A reboot will likely solve the issue

Comment: @ravery I don't know if the new desktop should be relevant as I use Kubuntu (KDE), but I will reboot as soon as my backup is in place.

Comment: KDE does not use wayland; however, the update still might have changed the profile.

Comment: @ravery Reboot did not solve the problem.

Comment: I got the same error after do-release-upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same thing happened to my when upgrading Mate to 17.10.

I went to System -> Preferences -> Look and Feel -> Language Support.

I'd previously selected English (UK) as my menu/windows language so on first opening this up I was prompted to upgrade, which I did.

My intention, and what I went on to do, was to change the "keyboard input method system" from "XIM" to "None".  Rebooted, and that seemed to clear the error message at login without any other ill effects - so far!

My logic... I don't have ibus on my machine and I didn't see the need for it if I don't need exotic fonts.  My default display manager is lightdm, so that would trip the first condition in the 21_ibus.rc file, taking me to line 6, which seems to disable the IBUS_SYNC mode and force XIM.  Again, not installing ibus, so can't use the ibus-deamon, therefore I can't have the XIM option - so I switched the keyboard option, as indicated above, and that seemed to work.

To do that on KDE open a terminal and type

```
 im-config -n none
```

Suspect it's a minor configuration issue, but would welcome learning if there's a more robust solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue after upgrade to 17.10. Temporary work around by set the keyboard input method system to none in language support.

Comment: Where is that setting in Kubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1007423) I would suggest that you [subscribe to it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug) so that you can be notified about progress. You should also click and answer the "Does this bug affect you?" question so that the developers can get an idea of the extent of the issue.

Comment: I am not sure this is indeed the case. I am able to write in Greek, english and German (Αβγδςüäö) without any problems. Also this bug seems to be quite old whereas I have encountered the above message only after updating from 17.04 to 17.10.

Comment: @Bruni I'm not certain either, it could be a regression, or not.  However as the bug was never Assigned and I can't seem to find anything that states it was fixed, it seemed a logical response.  Perhaps someone will come along and provide an answer that's more to your liking. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Bruni: I don't use KDE, nor fcitx, so can't directly check, but nearest thing I can find to help show you options I was referring to is here...

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-language-linux/

...where you can see the "keyboard input method system" for GTK, and, what I assume is the equivalent "Configure input method" for KDE.

Again, I don't have ibus, so there's no point trying to start xim server from ibus deamon, which is why selecting "None" is a convenient fix for my requirements. If you have fcitx installed and you have fcitx set in your "Configure input method" and you're still tripping an ibus trap then there's a configuration problem somewhere down the /etc/profile.

Comment: Thank. I am aware of these settings. However, there is no option to select the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I run into almost the same error. I have reinstalled ibus using Synaptic. All Good now!

[image: ibus Synaptic reinstall]

I hope it works for you as well.

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. As already mentioned in the question, installing ibus was not an option for me, as this led to a much more severe problem.