# Error found when loading /etc/profile in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 19.04

Everytime when I login to my user (UBUNTU 19.04), after I type the password and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get this error message:

```
error found when loading /etc/profile  
cat: /etc/X11/default-display-manager: no such file or directory
cat: /etc/X11/default-display-manager: no such file or directory
```

as a result the session will not be configured correctly

The last software's that I installed that could have messed up my Ubuntu were:

- Nautilus file manager
- Gnome Tweaks
- Safe Eyes
- Plank

Any help to fix that error would be appreciated.

EDIT: [image: This shows after i open "Ubuntu Software" app]

Comment: I hope the below link might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966775/error-found-when-loading-etc-profile

Comment: Doesn't seems to be the same kind of error?

Comment: `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` gives any output?